# Где хранить id всей одежды в игре?

Tags: java, массивы

Пишу игру (на Android), одной из особенностей которой является кастомизация внешнего вида игрока. Есть класс `Character`:

```java
// Одежда персонажа -----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Головной убор
static byte dress_head;
// Верх
static byte dress_top;
// Низ
static byte dress_bottom;
// Обувь
static byte dress_shoes;

// Броня персонажа 

------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Шлем
static byte armor_head;
// Нагрудник
static byte armor_top;
// Поножи
static byte armor_bottom;
// Защитные сапоги
static byte armor_shoes;
```

У класса `Character` есть поля, отвечающие за хранение `id` предметов одежды. Всего слотов под одежду `8`, `4` под броню и `4` под одежду.

Вопрос: где мне хранить `id` всей одежды в игре? Если в массиве, то в каком файле?

Comment: Нужно реализовывать подобие `Inventory` и `Paperdoll`. Если работа с внешностью, то `Appearance`.

Comment: Немного странный вопрос. Но, вы можете хранить в БД, вы можете в Файле, в котором будет в каком-то формате храниться ваш инвентарь, например, через запятую. Или, можете хранить в рамках 1 класса, куда будете добавлять ваш класс с инвентарем, но тогда, при каждом входе в игру, инвентарь придется делать заново :-)

Answer (score 1):

Не углубляясь в конкретную технологию и язык программирования, все `id` экипировки можно хранить несколькими способами:

- как *перечисление `enum`*. При этом отпадает необходимость в `id` как таковом. Просто у вас будет объявлен `enum`, где будут перечислены все типы экипировки, и в нужный момент полю класса присваиваете конкретное значение `enum` (по мне, это **самый предпочтительный** вариант). Если все же важно хранить именно id, то можете для каждого значения `enum` определить, какое целое число соответствует конкретной экипировке.
- как *константный массив* либо *хеш-таблица*, где индексом будет являться `id` вещи, а значением - сама вещь (т.е. по факту, этот массив инициализируется
  единожды при запуске приложения).
- *в файле*, который загружается в тот же самый массив. Это может быть
  как `xml`, `json`, так и текстовый или бинарный файл.
- *в базе данных*.

Answer (score 0):

## Пишу, исходя из тех данных, что предоставили.

Я предлагаю реализовать класс Equip_Inventory, который будет хранить все данные об экиперованном инвентаре игрока.Объект EquipInventory должен хранить Имя сохранения *string(если игра имеет сохранения более 1-го) , массив Объектов Класса Equipments(ID вещи *int(для вывода нормального инвентаря),тип занимаемой ячейки инвентаря *int , кол-во здоровье вещи max *int(),текущее здоровье вещи *int).

При создании игры создаём объект Equip_Inventory и выводи его во внешний файл(но сам Equip_Inventory  храним до выхода из сохранения в меню). При загрузке игры обращаемся к имеющемуся файлу с именем сохранения.Если вдруг есть сохранение без файла с EquipInventory(вдруг удалил случайно) , то генерим пустой EquipInventory. При измении инвентаря МОМЕНТАЛЬНО(это значит не до закрытия инвентаря или выхода из игры в меню) произвести выгрузку во внешний файл.